# Detect transitions in a list of objects

Tags: c#, algorithm, detection

I have an ordered list of objects (named LO).
Each object (named Ob) is a list of one or more int? elements (`List <int?>`), such as: `<30> or <30, null> or <null> or <28, 30>`, etc. **Edit:** In this list each element is unique.

I need to detect (and count) transitions in the list of objects, a transition being a certain sequence in the order of objects in the LO list. (**Edit:** I use `->` to indicate the next object. Ex. `<A> -> <B>` are 2 objects in the list of objects LO: say the 3rd is `<A>` and the 4th is `<B>`:

```
<A> -> <B> :transition
<A> -> <null> -> <B> or  <A> -> <null> ->...-> <null> -> <B> : transition
<A> -> <A,B> -> <B or  <A> -> <A,B> ->...-> <A,B> ->B :transition
<A> -> <null> -> <A> : transition
```

The `<A> -> <AB> -> <A>` is the exception, it is not a transition, and of course any combination of repeating `<A>-><A>`, `<null> -> <null>`, `<A,B> -> <A,B>`, etc. is not a transition.

Edit: Transitions only sequences that start with single objects (like  ) and end with single objects (like ).  ->  ->  is not a sequence of elements that identify a transition.

How can I do that? My idea would be to detect the `A -> (*)A -> A` pattern as the exception. Should I pre-filter the list to exclude repeating data?

Comment: Your definition of a transition is unclear.  To clarify it, how many transitions are there at which steps of the following sequence?  `<> -> <null, null> -> <1, 2> -> <1, null, 2> -> <2, null, 1> -> <2, 1> -> <>`  Is every step a transition?  Are some not?  Do some steps count as 2 transitions?

Comment: I need some clarification as well. To summarize: you have a list of sequences and every sequence is a list of `int?`s. E.g. sequence1 contains `<30>`, sequence2 contains `<30,null>`. The list of sequences contains sequence1 and sequence2. How would these sequences be noted in your notation: `30,30->null` or `30->30,null`. Would `30,30,null` be equivalent? How many transitions does this example have? And when is something a transition? When the next not null value is not the same as the current value? Why is `A->null->A` a transition?

Comment: @btilly Transitions are only from starting single value <A> or <B> or <C>, etc. to ending different single value. Order is not important. <A,B> is the same with <B,A>. There are no double transitions. <A> -> <A,B,null,C> -> <C> is a single transition. In your example there are no transitions as there is no single value to be found.

Comment: @venerik <A> -> <null> -> <A> is a transition because in my project it is considered that by going through a null value, a transition was concluded. <A> -> <null,B> -> <A> are 2 transitions. <A> -> <A,B> -> <A> is no transition. There are no multiple null values per object, only 1/object. For example: <A, null,null> is only <A,null>. Also: <A,B> is the same with <B,A> as noted above.

Comment: Sorry, I've voted down. It's still unclear.

Comment: @venerik For your questions: 1. How would these sequences be noted in your notation: 30,30->null or 30->30,null. Would 30,30,null be equivalent? Answer: No. An example is:

Comment: @venerik Each element in a sequence is unique.  For your questions:  Q1. 'How would these sequences be noted in your notation: 30,30->null or 30->30,null. Would 30,30,null be equivalent?' Answer:  I use -> to indicate the next sequence. Example: el1: <29,30>, el2:<null>, el3:<30>, el4:<29>, etc. Q2: 'And when is something a transition?' Transitions defined in the initial question + Transitions are only from starting single value like <A> to ending different single value like <B>, intermediary multi value sequences <A,B,C> cannot be used to define a transition. <A>, <null>, <A> is a transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I created a program (also available on [dotnetfiddle.com](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F55vFx)) with which I tried to fulfill your requirements. But I still think your specifications are unclear.

This is what I've implemented:

- A list of objects (`LO`) can contain objects (`OB`).
- An (`OB`) is a list of `String` (must be replaced  with `int?` in your scenario).
- An `OB` is treated as a `Set`. Duplicates are allowed but ignored.
- `OB`s are the same when they contain the same `Strings`.
- When the `LO` is empty, transitions is 0
- When the `LO` contains only one `OB`, transitions is 0
- When the first `OB` or the last `OB` in the `LO` have more than one `String`, transitions is 0
- The number of transitions is increased by one when two subsequent `OB`s are not the same.

I added a few remarks in the output because I don't understand what you mean.

**Output**

```
[A] -> [B] : 1

[A] -> [null] -> [B] : 2

[A] -> [null] -> [null] -> [null] -> [null] -> [B] : 2

[A] -> [A,B] -> [B] : 2

[A] -> [null] -> [A] : 2

[A] -> [A,B] -> [A] : 2
Why is this not a transition but an exception?

[A] -> [A,null] -> [A,null,null] -> [A] : 2
[A,null] and [A,null,null] are considered equal as per your second comment.

[A] -> [A,B,null,C] -> [A] : 2
As per your first comment.

[A] -> [A,B] -> [B,A] -> [A] : 2
Second and third OB are equal as per your first comment.

[A] -> [null,A] -> [B] : 2

[A] -> [A,B,C] -> [B] : 2
Why is this not a transition as per your fourth comment?
```

**Source code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static string A = "A";
    public static string B = "B";
    public static string C = "C";
    public static string NULL = "null";

    public static void Main()
    {   
        var lo = new LO();
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.Add(new OB{B});
        lo.DisplayResult();

        lo.Clear();
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.Add(new OB{NULL});
        lo.Add(new OB{B});
        lo.DisplayResult();

        lo.Clear();
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.Add(new OB{NULL});
        lo.Add(new OB{NULL});
        lo.Add(new OB{NULL});
        lo.Add(new OB{NULL});
        lo.Add(new OB{B});
        lo.DisplayResult();

        lo.Clear();
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.Add(new OB{A,B});
        lo.Add(new OB{B});
        lo.DisplayResult();

        lo.Clear();
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.Add(new OB{NULL});
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.DisplayResult();

        lo.Clear();
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.Add(new OB{A,B});
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.DisplayResult("Why is this not a transition but an exception?");


        lo.Clear();
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.Add(new OB{A,NULL});
        lo.Add(new OB{A,NULL,NULL});
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.DisplayResult("<A,NULL> and <A,NULL,NULL> are considered equal as per your second comment.");

        lo.Clear();
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.Add(new OB{A,B,NULL,C});
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.DisplayResult("As per your first comment");

        lo.Clear();
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.Add(new OB{A,B});
        lo.Add(new OB{B,A});
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.DisplayResult("Second and third OB are equal as per your first comment");

        lo.Clear();
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.Add(new OB{NULL,A});
        lo.Add(new OB{B});
        lo.DisplayResult();

        lo.Clear();
        lo.Add(new OB{A});
        lo.Add(new OB{A,B,C});
        lo.Add(new OB{B});
        lo.DisplayResult("Why is this not a transition as per your fourth comment?");
    }
}

// list of objects (LO) = list<OB>
public class LO : List<OB>
{
    public void DisplayResult(string message = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}",this,CountTransitions());
        if(message != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private int CountTransitions()
    {
        if(this.Any()== false || this.Count == 1) return 0;

        var first = this.FirstOrDefault();
        var last = this.LastOrDefault();

        // first OB and last OB must have exactly one element.
        if(first.Count != 1 || last.Count != 1) return 0;

        var transitions = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < this.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            // when current OB and next OB are not the same, it is a transition
            transitions = IsTransition(this[i],this[i+1]) ? transitions + 1 : transitions;
        }
        return transitions;
    }

    private bool IsTransition(OB lhs, OB rhs)
    {
        var lhsSet = new SortedSet<String>(lhs);
        var rhsSet = new SortedSet<String>(rhs);
        return lhsSet.SetEquals(rhsSet) == false;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(" -> ", this.Select(x => x.ToString()));
    }
}

// objects (OB) = list<int?>
public class OB : List<String>
{
    public override String ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("[{0}]", String.Join(",", this));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Your answer was the basis for my implementation, especially the IsTransition function.